# How to get nodes of Json using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I have a JSON and i want to get its node under a Node, but net getting how cani get it: Here is the JSON:

```
{
  "price": {
    "VPO": 125,
    "MSRP": 129.99,
    "ONSALE": 99.97,
    "a_bucks": 3.75
  },
  "short_info": {
    "product_name": "MARMOT PRECIP JACKET",
    "category": "WOMEN'S",
    "weight": {
      "lbs": 0.6,
      "kg": 0.27
    },
    "SKU": "KNXSU921",
    "part_info": "#46200",
    "rating": 4,
    "out_of_stock": false
  },
  "product_variants": {
    "XS": {
      "Arctic Navy": {
        "InStock": true,
        "Colorcode": "HMN",
        "InStore": {
          "NANAIMO": {
            "value": "true",
            "code": "154"
          }
        }
      },
      "Black": {
        "InStock": true,
        "Colorcode": "HMN",
        "InStore": {
          "NANAIMO": {
            "value": "true",
            "code": "154"
          }
        }
      },
      "Blue Sea": {
        "InStock": true,
        "Colorcode": "HMN",
        "InStore": {
          "NANAIMO": {
            "value": "true",
            "code": "154"
          }
        }
      },
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get Elements's (Nodes) name under XS, i.e. "Arctic Navy", "Black", "Blue Sea" etc.

I have used following code:

```
$.each(dataObj.product_variants.XS, function (i, item) {
  alert(item)
});
```

But not getting how can i get the required output. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe a trivial remark, but your JSON snippet is not well formatted. Have you already checked this out?

Comment: @AlbertoDeCaro, yes, i just coped and pasted only required elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
$.each(dataObj.product_variants.XS, function (i, item) {
  alert(i)
});
```

It can be achieved through javascript also

```
for(var i in dataObj.product_variants.XS) {
  alert(i)
});
```

If your dataObj.product_variants.XS would have been array, **i** would have been index of the element.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need jQuery for this. You can use normal JavaScript:

```
Object.keys(dataObj.product_variants.XS)
```

This will return an array of the keys. e.g.

```
[ "Arctic Navy", "Black", "Blue Sea" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Use `Object.keys()` to get the keys of a object

```
 var keys = Object.keys(dataObj.product_variants.XS);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zeoj9xd8/

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    $.each(Object.keys(obj.product_variants.XS), function (i, item) {
    alert(item)
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qejss4yj/